# Provide App service security in Azure solutions

Tags: azure, service, azure-web-app-service, paas, azure-webapps

I have a click once windows application which already has authentication n Authorization built in. Earlier i used to deploy it on physical server n share the location with users so that they can install it n use it. But now we have decided to deploy it on azure PAAS service (App service ). But currently url is geting access by anyone which i want to restrict. Currently my organization AD is not synced with Azure AD. So not able to use Azure AD for authentication.
Kindly provide some better solutions other than restricting users based on IP.

Comment: why not make the home page itself behind authorization? that way, anybody who comes, must login before proceeding if it is going to be available over the public net.

Comment: its a windows click once application...so when user users app service url first application downloads & install happen on user machine. I want to restrict this download itlesf if the user is not from my organization

Comment: it would still work. they login, and once they successfully login, the download will start automatically. I cannot think of any other way :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a file download you can put it on Azure Blob storage for download and generate short-time SAS tokens.

Answer (score 0):

While IP address restrictions and Azure AD authentication would be one-efficient approach for your scenario. Since you do not want to go that route (due to environment limitations), If you wish you could authenticate users with the specified provider (Microsoft Account, Facebook, Google, Twitter or Any OpenID Connect provider). App Service provides built-in authentication and authorization support, so you can sign in users and access data by writing minimal or no code.

App Service uses federated identity, in which a third-party identity provider manages the user identities and authentication flow for you.  You can also use multiple sign-in providers.

So the simple process could be:

The option is Log in with . App Service redirects all anonymous requests to /.auth/login/**<**provider**>** for the provider you choose. If the anonymous request comes from a native mobile app, the returned response is an HTTP 401 Unauthorized.

Kindly checkout step-step instructions on the process/workflow:
[Configure your App Service or Azure Functions app to use Microsoft Account login](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#identity-providers)

If your WebApp is on VNet, you can have [service endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#adding-and-editing-access-restriction-rules-in-the-portal) enabled for Microsoft.Web, through access restrictions.

See- [Advanced usage of authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to)